# Angular observable is not working

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angular6

I'm trying to add a firebase phone auth to my app. I'm at the point where you need to create a reCAPTCHA object. I want to know the reCAPTCHA is solved or not.

In the template:

```
{{ recaptchaSolved | async | json }}
```

This is my component class:

```
export class AddComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  windowRef: any;
  @ViewChild('recaptchaContainer') recaptchaContainer: ElementRef;
  recaptchaSolved: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(
    private win: WindowService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.windowRef = this.win.windowRef;
    firebase.auth().useDeviceLanguage();

    this.windowRef.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(
      this.recaptchaContainer.nativeElement, // for visible recaptcha
      {
        size: 'small',
        callback: response => {
          console.log(`reCAPTCHA solved`);
          this.recaptchaSolved = of(true);
        },
        'expired-callback': () => {
          console.log(`reCAPTCHA expired`);
          this.recaptchaSolved = of(false);
        }
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {}
}
```

WindowService:

```
@Injectable()
export class WindowService {
  get windowRef() {
    return window;
  }
}
```

The problem is when the reCAPTCHA is solved I get "reCAPTCHA solved" logged in the console, but the observable does not update (it is null).

Comment: @Und3rTow thanks but error TS2345: Argument of type 'Observable<boolean>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<boolean, {}>'.
  Type 'Observable<boolean>' provides no match for the signature '(source: Observable<boolean>): Observable<{}>'.

Answer (score 2):

Use a source `Subject` and observe it.

```
export class AddComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  recaptchaSolvedSource = new Subject<boolean>();
  recaptchaSolved = this.recaptchaSolved.asObservable();

  constructor(
    private win: WindowService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    ...
    this.windowRef.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(
      this.recaptchaContainer.nativeElement, // for visible recaptcha
      {
        size: 'small',
        callback: response => {
          this.recaptchaSolvedSource.next(true);
        },
        'expired-callback': () => {
          this.recaptchaSolvedSource.next(false);
        }
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {}
}
```